# IE Search Provider: Specifying gTLD / Country-Specific Site

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer, google-search

I am based in the UK, and as such typically use `google.co.uk` as my search engine. However, my employer is based in continental Europe, and thus my internet proxy is located overseas.

As a result, IP geo-location presents a location outside of the UK. Google detects this, and as a result will redirect my searches from the address bar to a foreign Google domain.

This leads to "local" answers having a higher ranking, many of which are not written in English language!

Is there a specific search provider / URL I can give to IE which will use a specific gTLD of google (`.co.uk`), rather than performing the location-based redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Append /ncr to the URL - www.google.co.uk/ncr

You will subsequently get results from the UK domain.

In Chrome, right click on the text box within the Google UK homepage and choose "Add as search engine.." and complete the suggested directions. You can then type your search keyword directly in the address bar and the results will be served by Google UK.